# Class inheritance - stacking methods

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have seen this once, but I can't remember how to make it work again. Let's say I have three classes:

```
class CRoot { ... };

class CLevelOne { ... };

class CLevelTwo { ... };
```

Now, I have main function, where I'd like to go more in depth by using this syntax:

```
int main (void)
{
  CRoot myRoot ("This is root.");
  myroot.AddLevelOne("This is level one.").AddLevelTwo("This is level two.");
}
```

So the final construction of my classes looks like this:

```
+- This is root.
|+- This is level one.
||+- This is level two.
```

How to implement it so I can use syntax `something.Method1().Method2().MethodN(). ...;` ?

Comment: This is often called "method chaining"

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
struct CLevelTwo { };

struct CLevelOne {
    CLevelTwo * AddLevelTwo() {
        return new CLevelTwo();
    }
};

struct CRoot {
    CLevelOne * AddLevelOne() {
        return new CLevelOne();
    }
};

int main(){
    CRoot *root = new CRoot();
    root->AddLevelOne()->AddLeveTwo();
}
```

You can replace the pointers with references, but beware of memory leaks. Note that this code leaks too, but it is more manageable and managing lifetime of the objects should not be a big problem.

Comment: I had to -1 this, I am afraid, returning pointers you allocated in a function is just bad practice (who has ownership?), unless of course you returned it in a some kind of `shared_ptr<>`, which has a cost associated with it also.

Comment: That was a quick down-vote! Your solution would not build a tree unless it calls the constructor in the getter, and that would return a  non-const references from an r-value, I am not sure that is much better...

Comment: @Moo-Juice: also, I clearly mentioned that object lifetime has to be carefully taken care of

Comment: It was a quick downvote! :)  Don't take that the wrong way though, but returning objects allocated via `new` from a function is bad enough, but then doing it in obvious method-chaining effectively means it never gets deallocated unless you wrap that up in a `shared_ptr` or some such.  That's why I downvoted it.  Don't take it personally.

Comment: I am not taking it personally, but I think your statement saying that passing ownerwhip to another object is bad is not true. Are you saying all factory patterns are bad design? This is clearly what he wants to achieve here.

Comment: Objects allocated in the factory pattern (In C++ at least, where we don't have garbage collection), *should* be a shared pointer, or some kind of other pointer type.  Yes, the factory has to allocate it - but it should not return a naked pointer that "someone else has to deal with".  Shared pointers deal with this conundrum - so no, it doesn't break the factory pattern at all :)

Comment: Yes, they *should* return a smart pointer, of which std::shared_prt is not necessarily the best choice, I agree. However if the original poster has trouble dealing with delegation, i am not sure giving him a solution involving complex and recent c++ idioms would be very useful, whereas the factory pattern returning pointer is a well known and accepted design pattern.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28612/discussion-between-moo-juice-and-thibaut)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
struct Level2
{
    // See class Level1 below
};

struct Level1
{
    std::string               m_name;
    boost::shared_ptr<Level2> p_level2;
    Level1(const std::string name)
        : name(m_name)
    { ; }

    Level2& add_level_two(const std::string& name)
    {
      p_level2 = new Level2(name);
    }
};

struct Root
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Level1> p_level1;
    Level1& add_level_one(const std::string& name)
    {
      p_level1 = new Level1(name);
    }
};
```

With a little more thought, a base class, one could create this more generically.  Also the level numbers would have to be moved out of the method names.

Comment: Good use of `shared_ptr<>` here.  But everything is private in your example and what happens if one calls `add_level_xxx` twice?

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  I'll change `class` to `struct`.  It's a habit of typing `class`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just make `SomeMethod` return a reference of `*this`:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo& Add(SomeOtherThing& thing)
    {
        // Do the "add"...
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Now you can do:

```
Foo myFoo;
myFoo.Add(...).Add(...).Add(...);
```

It's just like how the assignment operator overload works.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the OP wants different classes to be returned other than `*this`... at least, that's how I read it.

Comment: Well, that is true. All of my classes actually have different kinds of information to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** After reviewing this with Thibaut, I propose the following solution:

```
class Node
{
private:
    std::string _name;
    std::list<Node*> _nodes;

public:
    Node(const std::string& name) : _name(name)
    {
    }; // eo ctor

    virtual ~Node()
    {
        for(std::list<Node*>::iterator it(_nodes.begin());
            it != _nodes.end();
            ++it);
            delete *it;
    }; // eo dtor


    Node* Add(const std::string& name)
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node(name);
        _nodes.Add(newNode);
        return newNode;
    }; // eo Add
}; // eo class Node
```